# I cannot find AllowPixelScrolling in Devexpress 10.2. Is there any other option? (winforms)

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have a devexpress version 10.2 datagrid. The item is to big and the vertical scrollbar(set to auto) doesn't appear

Do you know any workarround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pixel Scrolling feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR8tWFYevf0&index=6&list=PL8h4jt35t1whfPMpdOlISqtNI8E-nqCNr) was introduced in v13.1.
Starting from this version you can activate it via the [GridView.OptionsBehavior.AllowPixelScrolling](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsBehavior_AllowPixelScrollingtopic) option.
There are no workarounds to implement a feature that does not exist in 10.2. You need to upgrade your components suite version to 13.1.5 (or newest) to get the behavior as you want.